# Getting service unavailable error in scrapy crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a forum website with scrapy.
The crawler works fine if I have

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

But if I increase that number then I get this error

> 2012-12-21 05:04:36+0800 [working] DEBUG: Retrying http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=1580> (failed 1 times): 503
>   Service Unavailable

I want to know if the forum is blocking the request or there is some settings problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP status code 503, "Service Unavailable", means that (for some reason) the server wasn't able to process your request. It's usually a transient error. I you want to know if you have been blocked, just try again in a little while and see what happens.

It could also mean that you're fetching pages too quickly. The fix is not to do this by keeping concurrent requests at 1 (and possibly adding a delay). Be polite.

And you *will* encounter various errors if you are scraping a enough. Just make sure that your crawler can handle them.

Comment: how much delay should be fine and how much concurrent requests are fine. i don;t know much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette ; i would set concurrent requests to 1 and add a 1-5 second delay between the requests.

Comment: 1 request seems very less and it will take too much time. do the google and all other search engines follow that guidelines

Comment: there is no universal rule. it depends much on the site you are scraping, but doing it the fast way may end up getting you blocked...

Answer (score 2):

This answer maybe a bit late, but what worked for me is this. I added a header where I specified Mozilla/5.0 user agent. I then stopped getting "HTTP status code 503" error.

Code is below, just ran trough Amazon without issues. This code basically collects all links from Amazon's home page. Code is a Python programming language code.

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

    url = "http://www.amazon.com"
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    website = opener.open(url)

    html = website.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    for element in soup.find_all(['a','link']):
        link = element.get('href')
        print link
```